# No entiendo bien que hacen estos descriptores

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

[image: No entiendo los descriptores]
Los descriptores `__get__(self, objeto, owner)`, `__set___(self, objeto, value)` y `__delete__(self, objeto)`, no lo entiendo muy bien para que sirve y cual es su función en el código que ponen en el libro. Dicen que es para identificar el objeto y la clase, pero no los entiendo.

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

class Patas(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.patas = 0
  def __get__(self, objeto, owner):
    return self.patas

  def __set__(self, objeto, value):
    try:
      self.patas = int(value)
    except ValueError:
      print("No es un entero")

  def __delete__(self, objeto):
    del self.patas

class Animal(object):

  patas = Patas()

  def __init__(self, nombre, patas):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.patas = patas

  def muestra(self):
    print("El " + self.nombre + " tiene " + str(self.patas) + " patas.")

chucho = Animal("perro", "A")

chucho.muestra()
input()
```

Comment: Puedes leer la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: Lee mejor el libro porque eso de que sirven para "identificar el objeto y la clase" no tiene sentido. Parece que la frase que has leido se debe de estar refiriendo a otra cosa

Answer (score 1):

Tu clase `Animal` tiene un atributo llamado `patas`, pero no es un atributo normal. Si fuera un atributo normal, cuando haces dentro de `__init__()` o dentro de `muestra()` un acceso a `self.patas`, estarías accediendo **directamente** al valor almacenado ahi, pero no es el caso.

En tu caso `Animal.patas` es una instancia de la clase `Patas`, y esa clase es un *descriptor*. Eso cambia el acceso a `Animal.patas`.

Cuando intentes acceder para leer a `Animal.patas` (por ejemplo en `self.patas`) Python comprobará si `patas` tiene un método `__get__()` y en ese caso lo llama. Así que cuando invocas `chucho.muestra()` está ocurriendo lo siguiente:

1. Python busca el método `muestra()` dentro de la clase `Animal`. Lo encuentra.
2. Python invoca ese método así: `Animal.muestra(chucho)`, de modo que el método recibe en su primer argumento `self` el objeto sobre el que debe actuar.
3. El método intenta acceder a `self.patas` para leer su valor. En ese momento `self` es `chucho`, por lo que Python buscará `chucho.patas`.
4. Python no encuentra `chucho.patas` (el objeto no tiene ese atributo ya que en este caso es un atributo de la clase, no del objeto). Sigue buscándolo entonces en la clase de la que el objeto es instancia
5. Python encuentra el atributo `Animal.patas`
6. Python observa que `Animal.patas` es una instancia de otra clase (en concreto de la clase `Patas`) por lo que mirará si ese objeto implementa la interfaz de un *descriptor*, es decir, mirará si implementa un método `__get__()`.
7. Encuentra que sí, de modo que invoca ese método en la clase `Patas`. En concreto (esto empieza a liarse mucho), lo que invoca es `Patas.__get__(Animal.patas, chucho, Animal)`.
8. Lo que esa función retorne será el valor final que usará la función `muestra()`.

En este caso, ya que `__get__()` hace un `return self.patas` pero en ese momento `self` es `Animal.patas`, lo que está retornando en realidad es `Animal.patas.patas` (siendo el segundo `.patas` el atributo de ese nombre dentro de la clase `Patas`, el cual ha sido inicializado con cero.

De forma análoga el método `__set__()` se invocará cuando se intente asignar un valor a `Animal.patas`, lo cual ocurre por ejemplo en el constructor:

```
  def __init__(self, nombre, patas):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.patas = patas         # <----- AQUI
```

En ese punto del código `self.patas` se refiere a `chucho.patas`, el cual no existe (como antes expliqué, ver punto 4) sino que se refiere a `Animal.patas` que es una instancia de `Patas`, por lo que se invocará `Patas.__set__()` y se le pasará como parámetros `Animal.patas` (el atributo a modificar), `chucho` (el objeto que necesita usar el setter) y `patas` (el valor a asignar al descriptor).

En este caso el descriptor antes de meter el valor dentro de `self.patas` (que es ahora `Patas.patas`), verifica que sea un entero. Este es un ejemplo de por qué puede merecer la pena dar tantas vueltas. Puedes escribir descriptores que verifiquen si el tipo o rango de lo que se intenta asignar es correcto y rechacen el caso en que no lo sea (por eso al ejecutar tu código aparece el mensaje "No es un entero" y el valor de `Animal.patas.patas` sigue siendo cero).

**Nota** Si todo esto te parece muy complejo, es porque realmente es muy complejo. Los descriptores se consideran material *avanzado* que pocas veces necesitarás. Y cuando los necesites hay una forma más sencilla de programarlos usando el decorador `@property`).